# When updating an individual child record triggers update to parent, and child records can be updated all at once, how to manage efficiency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, parent-child

I have a parent `Order` that has many child `Item`s. There is a `status` attribute on both parent and children, and the statuses interact. For example, only when all `Item`s are `complete` can the parent `Order` be complete.

Think of it like a restaurant where the policy is to bring out all the food in a given `Order` at once. Each food `Item` goes through very statuses like `in_prep`, `being_cooked`, etc. to `complete` and when all `Items` are `complete`, then the `Order` is `complete`, and then it can be brought out, at which point all `Item` and the parent `Order` can have a status of `enjoyed_by_customer`

Extending this example, let's say the various line cooks at each part of the kitchen have a tablet where they can update statuses of specific `Items` and only those `Items` in their purview. The chef, however, can view the entirety of the `Order` and make updates to any individual `Item` status, because the chef is walking around and tweaking and tasting and making changes, with creative ability to change any `Item` at will. For example, maybe the line cook says the `Item salad` is `complete`, but the chef tastes it, says it needs more dressing, and sets it back to `in_prep`.

First, I built a dashboard for line cooks to mark specific `Items` in their purview. A line cook making salads, for example, should be able to view all the salads from all the `Orders` that are not `complete`, and make batch updates to all of them. For example, the last step might be garnish, so they can garnish a dozen plates all at once and then set all those salads to `complete`. This meant that I had thought to put a callback on the `Item` model that called a `set_status` method on the parent `Order`:

```
class Item
  after_update :set_order_status 
  # after_update so we know that the status on this Item is valid

  def set_order_status
    if self.status.changed?
      self.order.set_status
    end
  end
end

class Order
  def set_status
    new_status = calculated_somehow_from_item_statuses # eg if all items are 'complete', this returns 'complete'
    self.update_attributes(status: new_status)
  end
end
```

Second, I built an overall `Order` dashboard for the chef, where they can, again, modify statuses of any `Item` as well as other attributes on the `Order` itself. For example, maybe chef wants to mark the `Order` with a special discount or something. For efficiency's sake, I set up the `Order` dashboard to update the entire `Order` all at once using nested attributes. In other words, the submitted params are like:

```
 {
   "discount": "true",
   "items_attributes": [
     {"id"=>"1","status"=>"complete"},
     {"id"=>"2","status"=>"in_prep"},
   ]
 }

 # this way it's easy to just do:
 @order.update_attributes(params)
```

However, of course, because of the way the individual line cook's dashboards have been set up, `@order.update_attributes` is actually called once for the `@order` and then once again after each child `item` updates. **In other words, there's redundancy caused by the fact that child items can be both updated 1) individually & 2) en masse, where in either situation, the parent order should be updated at the end based on all child items collectively**.

My only thought on revising this is to adjust the `set_order_status` callback on the child Item, it isn't triggered if the item update is done at the `Order` level by a chef. In other words:

```
class Item
  after_update :set_order_status 
  attr_accessor: changed_by_chef

  def set_order_status
    if self.status.changed? && self.changed_by_chef == false
      self.order.set_status
    end
  end
end

# where updates from the chef's dashboard, rather than individual line cooks, will have changed_by_chef in params

 {
   "discount": "true",
   "items_attributes": [
     {"id"=>"1","status"=>"complete", "changed_by_chef"=>"true"},
     {"id"=>"2","status"=>"in_prep", "changed_by_chef"=>"true"},
   ]
 }

@order.assign_attributes(params) # assign statuses to child items and run validations
@order.set_status # this method calculates appropriate order level status based on validated child item statuses, and calls the final update_attributes to save everything
```

In this way, `@order.update_attributes` is effectively called once. However, this also feels somewhat hacky to me, and I'm wondering if there's a more conventional Railsy way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a background worker to check and update statuses? I think these type of scenarios are perfect for background processing.

Comment: Updates happen disparately enough (the restaurant example is just an example) that I don't need the resources to have a background worker do anything, it's fine to just have the updates triggered by user action

Comment: One way around this is by just straight up quering the association instead `def complete?; self.items.where.not(status: :complete).none?; end` and let it be the source of truth. Callbacks are rarely a good answer for anything with any degree of complexity. If your model has complex state transformations you'll want to look into gems like AASM or [state-machines](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines).

Comment: @max that method `complete?` would go into my method `calculated_somehow_from_item_statuses` in the callback, so the problem would still exist? or else where are you thinking of calling that method in the line cook dashboard vs chef order dashboard?

Comment: also i don't think this is that complicated, just this one little thing...

Comment: No that code is an example of `Order#complete?`. And enforces the business rule "An order cannot be complete unless all its items are complete" without relying on any state on the orders table.

Comment: right i understand, what I mean though is that for it to be used, it would be called like this inside the `Order#set_status` : `new_status = self.complete? ? "complete" : "in_prep"`. So in other words it's an implementation detail, but doesn't change the question I'm posing.... or have I completely misunderstood you? Sorry happy to move to chat

Comment: No its actually a completely different conceptual approach. Forget the callbacks and an item being responsible for updating the order which is a violation of the SRP. Instead let your database be the source of truth. Check if an order is complete by checking if its items are complete. Compare this to loading kids on a school bus. You do it by counting the kids. Not by asking the bus if its status is "loaded".

Comment: gotcha. the question is still being asked though, after each kid gets on the bus right? a kid gets on, then you count how many kids to see if the bus is full?

Comment: No the important thing is that you do the count before you drive off with the bus. Or in this case when an order transforms its state to completed. Whatever this entails. What you're doing violates the SRP since it makes Item responsible for the state of Order which is not a good thing.

Comment: @max in this example, once line cook marks the last item of an order as `complete`, the order should be complete without requiring the chef to have to mark the order as `complete`. The only way I can think of to achieve this without violating SRP is to have a background job that regularly runs `order.update_attributes(status:'complete') if order.complete? == true`. Using the bus example, a background job goes through each bus and says: "ok go, if you're full!" Is that the approach you're thinking?